# close the popup only click on the close & mask area using jquery

Tags: jquery

Please see this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/AYdGS/10/)

What I tried

**jQuery**

```
$("div.prod").click(function() {
    $("div.mask").css("display","");
});

$("div.mask,div.close").click(function() {
    $("div.mask").css("display","none");
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="prod">
    Product 1
</div>
<div class="prod">
    Product 2
</div>

<br style="clear:both"/>

<div class="mask" style="display:none">
    <div class="popup">
        <div class="close">X</div>
        <div class="details">product details will come here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.prod {
    width:100px;
    height: 150px;
    border:1px solid red;
    float:left;
}

.mask {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    opacity:0.8%;
     background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.55);
}

.popup {
    position:absolute;
    width:250px;
    height:205px;
    left:100px;
    top:50px;
    border:5px solid purple;
    background:#F5F5F5;
}

.details {
    width:220px;
    height:120px;
}

.close {
    cursor:pointer;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
}
```

I want to close the popup only click on the "**close**" button and the "**mask**" area...

But my script close the popup where ever click on the popup.

I am searched this error on google but i can't to find.

Product details should be inside `<div class="mask"`. eg site [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/maskme/dpkiidbpeijnaaacjlfnijncdlkicejg/details)

Any one please help me.

Advance thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check over `event.target` if element desired has been clicked:

```
$("div.mask,div.close").click(function(event) {
    var $target = $(event.target);

    if ($target.hasClass("mask") == true
     || $target.hasClass("close") == true) {
        $("div.mask").css("display","none");
    };
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AYdGS/13/

Comment: thanks for your quick response...please see my question i mentioned `Product details should be inside <div class="mask"`...

Comment: wow...you really great.....man....thanks a lot.....if i am able to give upvote more than one,surely i will give 1000000..... votes

Comment: Lol, not a problem. See this link to learn more about jQuery event object: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/